# Why do I need to cast an object who was casted with an interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, casting

In java Lets say we have a class **Fruit** who implements **Edible**

```
public interface Edible {
    public boolean isEdible();
}

class Fruit Implements Edible{
    public String getDueDate(){
        return this.dueDate;
    }
    public boolean isEdible(){
        return True;
    }
}
```

and **Person** class

```
class Person{
    public void eats(Edible fruit){
        fruit.getDueDate();
    }
}
```

and I do the following

```
Edible apple = new Fruit();
Person p1 = new Person()
p1.eats(apple)
```

but it won't work because I need to cast it to Fruit again like this says the compiler:

```
class Person{
    public void eats(Edible fruit){
        Fruit fruit = (Fruit) fruit;
        fruit.getDueDate();
    }
}
```

Why is that? I thought I was be able to access the methods of the object without casting it.

Comment: Does `Edible` actually declare an `isEdible` method?

Comment: The only thing you know about the variable, is it's `Edible`, you should not cast the object in this case, as you can't guarantee what it "actually" is, only that's `Edible`

Comment: And why the hell is an Edible implementing an isEdible method that returns *false*? Is it edible or not?

Comment: *"I thought I was be able to access the methods of the object without casting it."* - You can only access the methods which the interface itself defines, this guarantees that any implementation which implements the interface will provide the functionality described by the interface. So I could pass `Pig` to your `eats` method and, so long as `Pig` implements `Edible`, it will work

Comment: sorry for that I was trying to convey my Doubt with an example I'm not a native speaker the whole point is why I need to cast the the object who has been casted before to an interface if I want to use one of objects methods, not only the ones who has been implemented by the interface

Comment: @MadProgrammer I already fixed my question I realized I didn't Formulate it well.

Comment: @LuisDavis It still doesn't change the fact of the case that `Edible` does not define the method you are trying to call.  You could "test" of an instance of a class, but that becomes a code nightmare as you try and test for all the possible cases

Comment: @MadProgrammer so  that means that in general if I assign an object to a interface reference variable I can not access(call) both the methods of the object and interface but just the interface methods?

Comment: @LuisDavis So long as the method you are passing it to only expects the `interface`, yes.  This is what polymorphism is all about. The point is, don't make assumptions about what data you are been passed. You could, for example, create an interface called `Vegetarian` which has a method `eat(Fruit fruit)` and have person implement this, as an extended idea (obviously you'd want to allow them to eat vegetables are well)

Comment: Assigning an expression to a variable of a given type is _telling_ the compiler you want to forget everything about that variable except that it's of the specified type.

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the methods defined by the interface without casting it. The problem here is your variable assignment. Your method accepts an object of type `Edible` as a parameter, but your local variable is of type `Fruit`. `Fruit` is a type of `Edible`, but the compiler cannot confirm that the object you passed in is a `Fruit` and not some other `Edible` until runtime. (Try passing another type of `Edible` to that method -- you'll end up with a `ClassCastException`).

As some commenters pointed out, you don't actually include your definition of `Edible` in this post. If you want to be able to call `isEdible()` on any `Edible`, your interface definition should look something like this:

```
public interface Edible {
    boolean isEdible();
}
```

If you've done that, you should be able to call `isEdible()` on the `Edible` parameter.

```
public void eat(Edible food) {
    food.isEdible();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake making my example the problem is not defining the method in the interface, I fixed it now check again please.

Comment: I assumed that you had written the interface and just didn't include it in the post, but I put the information there just in case.